# Qt : reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am new to Qt, and today I've been trying to adapt my application to work with `QFuture` to concurrently run some tasks off the main thread.

I have a method which changes the saturation value of a `QImage` which returns a `QPixmap` object to be drawn to my `QGraphicsView`.  This all worked fine not using threads, but obviously it is extremely intensive on the main thread so I wanted to move it off.

I read a few articles regarding Threading in Qt, and found that v5 supports a [concurrent run functionality](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#details), this sounded perfect for my use case as I thought I would just be able to dispatch my functions onto a new thread as in the snippet below:

```
void MainWindow::on_slideSaturation_valueChanged(int value)
{
    QFuture<QPixmap> future = QtConcurrent::run(slider->modifySaturation, value, image);
    future.waitForFinished();
    image = future.result();
    renderImageToCanvas();
    modified = true;
}
```

However I get the error `reference to non-static member function must be called`.
This error is being called from my Sliders class, I know I haven't declared the method as static, but when I do it causes a whole heap of errors - is there any way I can pass this method to my concurrent call without it being declared as static?

Sliders.h

```
class Sliders
{    
public:
   Sliders();

   enum Member { RED, GREEN, BLUE, BRIGHTNESS, CONTRAST, HUE, SATURATION, LIGHTNESS };

   QPixmap modifySaturation(int, QPixmap);
   void setMember(enum Member, int);
   int getMember(enum Member);

private:
    int m_redValue;
    int m_greenValue;
    int m_blueValue;
    int m_brightnessValue;
    int m_contrastValue;
    int m_hueValue;
    int m_saturationValue;
    int m_lightnessValue;
};
```

Comment: Using `QPixmap` in other than the main thread is not safe. Use `QImage` instead.

Comment: Could you suggest a better way of structuring my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `QtConcurrent::run` like this:

```
QFuture<QPixmap> future = QtConcurrent::run(slider, 
                                            &Sliders::modifySaturation,  
                                            value, image);
```

But I think you are using it wrong anyway. Your `on_slideSaturation_valueChanged` slot, which I assume to be executed in the main thread, will be blocked until `future.waitForFinished()` returns.

Comment: Thanks Hank, any suggestions on how I could improve on this?  As I said I'm new to Qt, finding the whole experience both fun and confusing!  Thanks.

Comment: @Alex In your scenario, I would use a worker object which emits a signal upon finishing the task. Move this worker object to a new thread using [`QObject::moveToThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread). Send the `QImage` object to the main thread using that signal. Then use this `QImage` object to update your GUI.

Comment: Thank you thuga, I'll do some more doc reading and have another go at using signals and slots

Comment: @Alex There is a good example of a worker object in the [`QThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#details) docs.